# How do I getting chunk file error free angular build

Tags: angular, build, virtual-machine, angularbuild

I am working on Virtual Machine. I am getting pull from bitbucket, then run *npm i* command. code work for the *ng serve*, but I am getting error for *ng build*. I was also try *ng build --prod*.

Error
*

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 10.8 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 315 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 716 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1020 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 9.91 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-06-03T10:18:11.181Z - Hash: daf9a871da5f2b3e6e93 - Time: 40059ms
```

*

I was try all the solution but, still I am getting the same error.

Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTjsZ.png)

Comment: This is not an error, but a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

From the attached image, I can see the build is successful. And the build output you have posted also does not have any error. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If the build is successful then why it will not showing, that build is successful?

Comment: Why should I am getting the list of chunk file?